# Grammatikspiel, Lernspiel, Game für die Fälle Akkusativ, Dativ, Nominativ und Genitiv

Tags: dative, accusative, learning, nominative

Ich suche ein Lernspiel, um die Fälle Nominativ, Akkusativ, Dativ und Genitiv mit Kindern zwischen 8 und 12 Jahren zu üben.

Eine [Suche nach `Grammar` bei Github](https://github.com/search?q=Grammar&type=topics&p=4) hatte u.a. [Deutsch Grammatik](https://github.com/surfmuggle/deutschgrammatik/tree/master) ergeben, doch das Spiel ist nicht mehr online.

Kennt jemand ein solches Spiel, welches auch empfehlenswert ist?

Answer (score 1):

Leider kenne ich kein Spiel, aber ein Gedicht von Christian Morgenstern, dass sich mit dem Thema befasst:

```
Der Werwolf

Ein Werwolf eines Nachts entwich    
von Weib und Kind und sich begab    
an eines Dorfschullehrers Grab    
und bat ihn: Bitte, beuge mich!

Der Dorfschulmeister stieg hinauf
auf seines Blechschilds Messingknauf
und sprach zum Wolf, der seine Pfoten
geduldig kreuzte vor dem Toten:

„Der Werwolf“ – sprach der gute Mann,
„des Weswolfs, Genitiv sodann,
dem Wemwolf, Dativ, wie man’s nennt,
den Wenwolf, – damit hat’s ein End.“

Dem Werwolf schmeichelten die Fälle,
er rollte seine Augenbälle.
Indessen, bat er, füge doch
zur Einzahl auch die Mehrzahl noch!

Der Dorfschulmeister aber mußte
gestehn, daß er von ihr nichts wußte.
Zwar Wölfe gäb’s in großer Schar,
doch „Wer“ gäb’s nur im Singular.

Der Wolf erhob sich tränenblind –
er hatte ja doch Weib und Kind!!
Doch da er kein Gelehrter eben,
so schied er dankend und ergeben.
```

Quelle: [literaturkritik.de](https://literaturkritik.de/einzigartiger-fall-der-faelle-christian-morgensterns-gedicht-der-werwolf,23902.html)

Für deutschsprachige Kinder ist das vielleicht lustig und motivierend.
Für nicht deutschsprachige würde ich es wohl eher nicht empfehlen

Comment: Eigentlich müsste man die Antwort als off-topic flaggen, denn sie ist keine Antwort auf die Frage. Länge und Struktur erlauben jedoch nicht, sie in einen Kommentar zu wandeln. Andererseits ist es schade um den Inhalt. Vielleicht kann man sie 2 Wochen als Kleinod bestehen lassen und dann erst löschen?

Comment: Ja, stimmt. Es ist keine Antwort auf die Frage (und ich habe auch keine). Da niemand bisher geantwortet hat, wollte ich eine Alternative bieten weil ich das Thema bei meinen Kindern so eingeführt habe und das gut funktioniert hat. Ich lösche sie gerne selbst, wenn es andere Antworten (diesmal auf die Frage) gibt.

Comment: Bitte nicht löschen. Ich verstehe, dass Stackexchange kein Forum sein soll, doch ich finde die Antwort gut und würde Sie gerne hier wiederfinden, statt mir lokal eine Kopie zu speichern.